# How to reload session without re-login

Tags: php, session, redbean

I have this code:

```
<?php
$data = $_POST;
$lastchange = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
if(isset($data['do_change'])) {
    $user = R::findOne('users', 'login = ?', array($login));
    if ($user) {
        $user->lastchange = $lastchange;
        $user->login = $data['newlogin'];
        R::store($user);
    }
}
?>
```

After I update user data, the session data is not up to date. Can I somehow, after that script, end the session and start it again, without the user needing to login again?

This is the login part:

```
if (isset($data['do_login'])) {
    session_start ()
    if ($response != null && $response->success) {
        $user = R::findOne('users', 'login = ?', array($data['login']));
        if ($user) {
            if (($data['password'] == $user->password)) {
                $_SESSION['logged_user'] = $user;
                header('Location: pcab.php');
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `R::store()` it is not a pure php.

Comment: Where is your `session_start()`

Comment: it s in other part of the code but anyway cuz this is like an editing script as y can see

Comment: _..this is like an edit script as y can see.._ Sure.. but you are talking about session issues and there is no code that handles any kind of session

Comment: ok as I understand I must show every movement

Comment: I saw your edit. put session_start() in the most top of your script, also add an exit() after the ehader function

Comment: I just added the login part...

Comment: ok thx that s like my 1st. question here)

Comment: What do you mean "reload session"? What's the actual problem here?

Comment: I just described the whole thing in the post man. long story short need to end session and start without re-entering  password and login

Comment: What do you want to achieve by reloading the session? You just want `session_write_close(); session_start();`?

Comment: ahh. I meant that I need to re-write users data(that 1st script is doing) then just log him out to let data update(I tried just to reload the page btw) and log him again but WITHOUT  entering pass)

Comment: So a "session reload" is your code that puts data into `$_SESSION` after login? Just call that again?

Comment: xd. its like 01:00 here I actually forgot thanks man. can y write this like an answer to let me mark you?

Comment: Add the code that actually populates the `$_SESSION` into the question. If you are executing that after your shown code, `exit;` will prevent that.

Comment: done. y can do it now

Comment: Also it seem you are using plain text passwords. You should use [`password_hash`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash) and [`password_verify`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify).

Comment: yes btw it s just a test but thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a session reload, you just need to update the session data after updating the user data.

```
<?php
$data = $_POST;
$lastchange = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
if(isset($data['do_change'])) {
    $user = R::findOne('users', 'login = ?', array($login));
    if ($user) {
        $user->lastchange = $lastchange;
        $user->login = $data['newlogin'];
        R::store($user);
        $_SESSION['logged_user'] = $user; // update the logged-in user
    }
}
?>
```